# How to handle exceptions when navigable class throws it?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

So I'm trying to navigate to some UserControl like that:

***MainWindowViewModel.cs***

```
      private void Navigate(string uri)
        {
            _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", uri, NavigationCompleted);
        }
```

In ModelView of navigable View I want to throw exception in constructor, return back to MainWindow and handle it.

***SomeUserControlViewModel.cs***

```
            try
            {
                //...throws some exception
            }
            catch (SomeCustomException)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
```

As I discovered, there is a callback ***NavigationCompleted***. It excecutes when navigation is done and as a parameter it provides ***NavigationResult*** with fields such as ***Result*** and ***Exception***.
But it always return ***Result*** with ***true*** and ***Exception*** with ***null***,
it doesn't matter if it's exception or normal situation.

Am I doing something wrong?

P.S. I'm sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple, you need to throw exception from the constructor, not in some method that constructor excecutes.

Edit: The issue where navigation callback always return positive result is because of async void method. I change it to Task and check it if task.Exception is null.

***My solution:***

```
       var method = SomeAsyncMethod();

       if (method.Exception != null)
             throw method.Exception;
```

Comment: Are you sure that your constructor doesn't catch the exception unintendedly? From looking at the code, the exact source of the exception shouldn't matter at all: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/1d4a9620cc6940dca4149f6fb1933eee7456bbe7/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Regions/RegionNavigationService.cs#L263

Comment: @Haukinger yeah, my mistake, I didn't know about details of async void methods and didn't mentioned it, that was because of them.

Comment: We're not getting `async` constructors anytime soon... perhaps we get `IInitializeAsync` (from Prism.Forms) in wpf? In dthe meantime, this is a good read on async construction: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html